# Маршрутизатор на FreeBSD

Tags: firewall, маршрутизация, freebsd

Ищу помощи ибо сам уже окончательно запутался с настройками.Нужно настроить FreeBSD (версия 9.1) где 3 сетевые карты, и каждая из них подключена в отдельный Свитч с разными сетями.  ![Схема][1]Нужно настроить так чтобы Отдел Сбыта, ОТК и сеть цеха могли связываться с компьютерами только в своей сети (см. схему). То есть каждая сеть существует отдельно. Но при этом компьютер Админа мог связываться с любым компьютером по любой сети, ну то есть по сути надо просто прописать маршрут в роутере с чем у меня и проблемы.  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogxhV.png

Comment: Свичи умные (802.1Q поддерживают)?

Answer (score 1):

На компьютере админа указываете либо основной шлюз адрес сервера с freebsd, либо на компьютере админа прописываете 3 маршрута к сетям через сервер freebsd.

Comment: так и каждый может поступить, и доступ будет не только у него. Надо именно настроить FireWall чтобы только его компьютер мог попадать в эти сети

Comment: ок, просто вы изначально про маршрутизацию спросили. Хорошо, тогда политика файрвола по умолчанию допустим DROP, и прописываете правила в  которых будет указан source ip  админа и ему ACCEPT.

Comment: а конкретно можешь написать команды как запретить всем, и разрешить только одному IP ?

Comment: Конкретно сам постарайся написать. Ниже человек ответил что для этого нужно почитать.

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте про pf. При помощи него можно организовать то, что вам требуется. Вот хорошая статья. [pf во free BSD](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-ipf_FreeBSD/index.html)

Comment: а вот если по этой статье делать http://www.opennet.ru/base/net/freebsd_gw.txt.html   ?вроде даже случай немного похож на мой.